# Magento : How to retrieve option information from a bundled product?

Tags: php, magento, bundle, observers

I have a bundled Product that contains 3 virtual products as options.

I have an observer that is listening to an event when an item is added to the cart and I'm having a hard time figuring out how to get the option information that I selected when looking at the product:
the start of the observer looks like this:

```
public function checkSubscriptionHierarchy(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
$event = $observer->getEvent();
$product = $event->getProduct();

...
```

the call to $product->getSku() returns the sku of the bundle product.  I'd love to be able to grab the sku of the option that I selected, but cannot figure out how to do that.

Thanks!

Comment: which event are you tying it to?

Comment: I was actually overriding addProduct and dispatching and event before calling parent::addProduct.

Comment: I ended up actually dealing with this by tying to checkout_cart_product_add_after and that seemed to have the info I needed in the QuoteItem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dealt with this by listening to event: `checkout_cart_product_add_after` and getting the info off the QuoteItem which worked out.